# Can an end user see the typescript code of an Angular application by using developer tools of browser

Tags: angular, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

Let's say I create a guard for a route in my angular application which checks whether a field has been set in localStorage previously and only then allows navigation to the guarded route. Can a user somehow figure out what guard is preventing the navigation to a route and also see it's code. The user can then manually set that field in localStorage and access the navigate to the guarded route.

Comment: Assume _anything_ you put client side they can read. Usually this isn't a problem because the endpoints providing the actual data are protected by authentication.

Comment: Since the browser has to know all the code, yes. You can e.g. uglify the code in production mode, but nevertheless there should be no sensitive data inside the application. Your approach is not safe even if this is impossible because using localStorage of the browser for security is not safe. Its easily accessible and cloneable. Maybe if it's invalidated/refreshed after a short time or if the user agrees because it's a private machine.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't have [`sourcemaps`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)#Source_mapping) enabled users won't be able to see your original *TypeScript* code, but only the transpiled version in JavaScript.
Though the transpiled JavaScript version can be close enough to the original code that it would be practically the same.

But even when further applying minification or uglyfying to obfuscate the code - in the end the browser has to be able to execute the and so all code must be readable by the browser and thus will be readable by the user. Any sufficiently skilled user is then able to easily inspect and reverse engineer your code to understand the checks your guard is performing.

If the guard only relies on a specific value in `localStorage` the user might even not need the code at all but may be able to just guess to required changes from inspecting the contents of `localStorage`.

Because of all of this it is not possible to **securely** store any private secrets or execute code that the user is not allowed to know/inspect. You can still use it disable the access to a specific route. But eventually **access control has to be implemented on the server-side** where it can not be manipulated by the user.